# VBox set fill width true specific to element

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there any way to set fillWidth true to specific children of VBox ?

**Curent Output :**

if VBox fillWidth = false set

[image: if VBox fillWidth = false set]

if VBox fillWidth = true set

[image: if VBox fillWidth = true set]

**Expected Output :**

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fillWidth` property itself is applied to all children.

However, you can use `HBox1.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE)` and `HBox1` will fill the width. 
(Since it looks like you are using Scene Builder, you can also use a sufficient big value.)

The other way around is also possible: Set `fillWidth` to true and limit the widths of the other `HBox` elements using the `maxWidth` property.